# IBM X3200 M2 Fan running at full speed? Noisy

Tags: ibm, ibm-xseries

One of the FANs (the one cooling the hard drives I think) in our IBM X3200 M2 started running at full speed and make a loud noise.

Anyone encountered this problem and know how to fix this?

Comment: Start by carefully feeling around the area of that fan for heat. There just might be a reason for it to be going full speed.

Comment: I tried feeling the HDDs, didn't seem hot to me. Still investigating...

Comment: Usually when I talk to IBM about these sort of issues they recommend a firmware upgrade. Check out their Bootable Media Creator (BMC), make a CD/USB image for your particular model, and see if the upgrade helps.  Beware, though - I've had failed firmware upgrades break systems completely in the past (but not on your particular model).

Answer (score 1):

Does the server have the RSA2 card? Log into it if so, or use the IBM tools from the operating system to see if you've got something going on with a component running hot. You should be able to get a read out of most major components and all the fans.

That being said, sometimes all you need to do is turn it off and on again.

Comment: Doesn't have RSA2 in it, will try to use the software tools to find the problem.